# How to highlight the last row of a gt table?

Tags: r, dplyr, gt

Is there a way to programmatically select the last row of a table in a pipeline and highlight it with `gt`?

Highlighting a particular row index is trivial:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(gt)

mtcars %>% 
  head(5) %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  tab_style(
    style = list(cell_fill(color = "lightblue")),
    locations = cells_body(columns = everything(), rows = 2)
  )
```

[image]

But I would like to highlight the *last* row. Surprisingly, using `tidyselect::last_col` appears to work, but I do not understand why?

```r
mtcars %>% 
  head(5) %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  tab_style(
    style = list(cell_fill(color = "lightblue")),
    locations = cells_body(columns = everything(), rows = tidyselect::last_col())
  )
```

[image]

I have tried a few approaches like `~ nrow(.)` and `+Inf`, but those fail. In addition, I would like to avoid having the index pre-determined because I would like to keep in a pipeline -- that is, I cannot do something like `LAST_ROW <- nrow(mtcars)` because of the number of rows is undetermined until the data goes through the pipeline.

Comment: `tidyselect::last_col` works here because both the columns and rows argument works with `tidyselect` helpers. I think this is the correct solution.

Comment: @Maël but even per the docs, `last_col` should select the last _column_ not the last _row_? What am I missing? And then why does `rows = length(tidyselect::last_col())` not work?

Answer (score 3):

This is one way to do it.  Simply supply the length of one of the columns.  I think it would be better to access the data frame from within the `tab_style` command, but I don't know if that's possible.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(gt)

mtcars %>% 
  head(5) %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  tab_style(
    style = list(cell_fill(color = "lightblue")),
    locations = cells_body(columns = everything(), rows = length(mpg))
  )
```

Comment: I like this. It still depends on knowing the columns of the underlying dataset upfront, but could work in a pinch. It's curious that `rows = length(tidyselect::last_col())` does not work, but  `rows = length(everything())` does work.